# Creating a loop with compare_means

Tags: r, ggpubr

I am trying to create a loop to use compare_means (ggpubr library in R) across all columns in a dataframe and then select only significant p.adjusted values, but it does not work well.

Here is some code

```
head(df3)
sampleID    Actio   Beta    Gammes  Traw    Cluster2
gut10   10  2.2 55  13  HIGH
gut12   20  44  67  12  HIGH
gut34   5.5 3   89  33  LOW
gut26   4   45  23  4   LOW


library(ggpubr)
data<-list()
for (i in 2:length(df3)){
data<-compare_means(df3[[i]] ~ Cluster2,  data=df3, paired = FALSE,p.adjust.method="bonferroni",method = "wilcox.test") 
}
Error: `df3[i]` must evaluate to column positions or names, not a list
```

I would like to create an output to convert in dataframe with all the information contained in compare_means output
Thanks a lot

Comment: any solution received on this?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(ggpubr)
data<-list()
for (i in 2:(length(df3)-1)){
new<-df3[,c(i,"Cluster2")]
colnames(new)<-c("interest","Cluster2")
data<-compare_means(interest ~ Cluster2,  data=new, paired = FALSE,p.adjust.method="bonferroni",method = "wilcox.test") 
}
```